# How to show loading Icon/ Spinner on APP_INITIALIZE in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi i would like to show the spinner icon until my Angular Application loads completely. And i have read that APP_INITIALIZER is used to load the needed dependency for the application. So i need to show the spinner/loading icon until APP_INITILIAZER lodes its dependency.  I am new to angular please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, put your spinner inside your app-root element...